# How to validate the results VSTS 2013 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am doing Load testing using VSTS 2013. I need to validate the results which was received. For example If, 800 report for created for 200 Users. Results are getting display with some values in Min(0.009), Avg(1.2), Max(9.5), 95%(7.03) etc... I need to know that the values are mentioned here is Transaction time in seconds for each user?

Comment: You might consider adding more information to you question, or placing some of your source code on it. In this question current state I believe you would not get the help you are after...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio test results are displayed in seconds, [you can see how to read the results here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385841.aspx). This time is calculated considering all requests, not users (min, max, average, 95%...). Basically, if your average is 1.2s, then a user will most likely have to wait 1.2 seconds per request on average.